# How to call an executable with Dll from a directory without this dll

Tags: powershell

I have a working directory a and
I have a directory b with an exutable and a dll which is used by the executable.

I want to launch the executable in the working directory.

With powershell I do that:

```
$env::path += ";C:\path\to\the\directory b"
```

Now I try to launch the executable from directory a

```
 executableName
```

the programm is launched but it fails to work because it can't find the dll.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: `env::path += directory b` is not valid PowerShell.

Comment: You want `$env:Path += ";C:\rooted\path\to\folder\containing\dll"` <-- remember the `;` before the path you want to add

Comment: No. with directory b added to the path. I can only access the the programm. Otherwise I get this error: "the term tsr is not recognied".
Although the programm is launched it doesn't work. the programm say I can't access the dll.

Comment: it say QSL.dll not found. But this dll is in the same dll as the executable

Comment: This is unusual, because when you look at [standard dll search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order), the application directory is always the first directory to search for DLLs. The app may change the standard search order though.

Comment: In your example you had missed the ":" after the drive letter, when trying to modify the path env var. Have you missed it again, when trying to follow Mathias's advice? Make sure to copy-paste Mathias's code exactly.

Comment: @zett42 I've used a dummy name because I don't want to make public the software the company is using.  the directory in the path is not a problem. The executable can be found after i've added to the path.(But not the dll)
Thanks for documentation about the search order of the dll.
Now I think the problem comes from the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the company that has done this executable file.
The problem comes from the file.
It's not a path related problem.